# Php : cant sumbit the good form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Sorry for my spelling

Hi, im trying to make a website showing internet forfeit, so in mySQL database i put all my information then I print it on my web page, the the user click on the forfeit he wants, it brings him to an other page that shows all the forfeit informations... In the while(), I'm making unique form for each forfeit, then on the

The problem here is that the only form sumbitted is the last one created

```
   include_once "DataBase/db.php";

            if($internet->num_rows != 0){
                    while($rows = $internet->fetch_assoc()){
                        $nom = $rows["nom"];
                        $id = $rows["id"];
                        $tech = $rows["technologie"];
                        $telechargement = $rows["telechargement"];
                        $televersement = $rows["televersement"];
                        $utilisation = $rows["utilisation"];
                        $prix= $rows["prix"];

                       echo '
           <form method="POST" action="Fournisseurs/Videotron.php" id="'.$id.'">

              <div class="boxes">
               <div class="[ price-option price-option--high ]">
                <div class="price-option__detail">
                   <span class="price-option__cost">'.$nom.'<br>$'.$prix.'</span>
                    </div>

                     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'"></input>
                     <input type="hidden" name="nom" value="'.$nom.'"></input>
                     <input type="hidden" name="tech" value="'.$tech.'"></input>
                     <input type="hidden" name="telechargement" value="'.$telechargement.'"></input>
                     <input type="hidden" name="televersement" value="'.$televersement.'"></input>
                     <input type="hidden" name="utilisation" value="'.$utilisation.'"></input>
                     <input type="hidden" name="prix" value="'.$prix.'"></input>

                       <div class="price-option__purchase">
                         <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('.$id.').submit();"> Submit </a>
                       </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    ';
                           }
        }
```

You can see what i'm talking about here : http://fournisseursquebec.com/Forfaits.php

just select internet

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a closing from tag in your loop.

Comment: Form id is wrong. Showing console error - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null". Your form id is 18, but in anchor tag you are submitting like document.getElementById(22).submit() this. id 22 is input type hidden.

Comment: @ManikandanS the form id attributes are definitely correct.  When you view the source they all match the corresponding getElementById().  The reason for the console error is there is no closing form tag so getElementById() cant find an improperly closed element.

Comment: @AdamKonieska yeah I accepted your answer. It's my mistake. I didn't noticed

Comment: Thanks a lot but now look on the website how it looks :/

Comment: @fabien put all your form tags inside the `.price-option__detail` div.

Comment: @AdamKonieska Thank you my friend ur really a god!

Comment: Can you finish the last sentence of the first paragraph, in order to make this more helpful to others? "In the while(), I'm making unique form for each forfeit, then on the" ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the closing `</form>` tag for every box. Now you have one big form with a lot of repeated fields:

```
<form method="POST" action="Fournisseurs/Videotron.php" id="'.$id.'">
box 1:
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'"></input>
.... box 2:
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'"></input>
...
```

The `name` attribute of the various `input` is the one that is sent and should be unique inside every `form`.

Just add the `</form>` tag in your `while` loop and it should work.

Comment: Oh thanks guys, now the problem is the loocking on the website :/